# Aptana won't generate phpdoc blocks for functions within classes

Tags: aptana, phpdoc

In Aptana, I have somehow broken the functionality to auto-generate phpdoc comments for functions within classes. It appears to only affect my current project.

Normally I can type /** on the line before a function and press enter, and Aptana will create a phpdoc comment with the correct @param values, etc. For some reason when I do this now Aptana creates 2 comments, one within the other. e.g.

```
/**
* /**
*
*/
*/
public static function getByLogin($loginID, $ip, $userAgent) {

}
```

It works normally if I try this for global functions. It also works for class variables and classes themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by right clicking the project then configure -> add php support. I don't understand how php support got removed, or how phpdoc was working on global functions without it, but it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

i thinks i saw this feature in Aptana 2 but it was remove from Aptana 3, i don't know why.

Comment: In the version 3 there is automatic comment section. Look in Commands->PHP. If you generate with shortcuts, you will have the auto comments.