# Automatic documentation plugin for Aptana IDE

Tags: php, plugins, documentation, aptana, documentation-generation

I was wondering if there was a documentation plugin for Aptana (the Eclipse plugin), that would automatically create the outline of documentation for methods, functions, properties and so forth. I've heard of ScriptDoc, but can't seem to figure out how it works.

I've previously worked in visual studio, where I found [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) to be much of a timesaver, and I would really like to see something similar for Aptana when I'm writing PHP.

Thank you

Comment: Related: [Aptana won't generate phpdoc blocks for functions within classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031680/aptana-wont-generate-phpdoc-blocks-for-functions-within-classes) - Apart from that  what should such a plugin do (for those readers who don't know *GhostDoc*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite late to the party, but just in case someone else stumbles upon this question like I have.

If you're looking for an Eclipse based IDE automatically create your PHPDoc, look into Zend Studio. There is even a default keystroke for it, and if you're type-hinting it will actually fill in some of the gaps.

It's nothing like GhostDoc, which even does some of the "duh" descriptions for you and allows you to copy down base-class/interfaces to inherits... PHP documentation has a few standards right now, phpdoc.org being the spearhead; even with that it's still relatively uncommon to see PHPDoc used correctly if at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard PHP Documentor tool called phpdoc. Here is a link: http://www.phpdoc.org

Hope it helps