# Generating DocBlock for a method in Aptana Studio

Tags: php, aptana, aptana3, phpdoc

I'm using Aptana Studio 3 for PHP development. I know there is a snippet for PHPDoc blocks generation for classes and methods (type doc, press ctrl+space and appropriate snippet is inserted). The problem is that it's only possible to use it for new methods, doc_f snippet inserts something like this:

```
/**
 * undocumented function
 *
 * @return void
 * @author  
 */
function functionName() {
}
```

So whenever I have a method I want to document, I still have to manually insert all data regarding arguments and returned value. I remember that in PDT (Eclipse) I used long time ago there was a convenient hotkey (ctrl+shift+j IIRC) that automatically filled all those PHPDoc params for a selected element, but it doesn't work in Aptana. Is there any better way for generating DocBlocks for PHP in Aptana Studio, other than just manually typing it in for each undocumented method and class?

Comment: I believe that is a feature only available in PDT, which does not get along well with Aptana Studio 3. From what I can tell it was on the eventual to-do list for Aptana but I cannot tell if they ever added it... If you figure this one out, I would really love to know.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like Aptana development has halted, last update was 8 months ago, so I guess I'll have to consider switching IDE again...

Comment: Maybe I'm just behind the times because I wait for Aptana to prompt me, but I just got a new update notification last week to move to 3.4 from 3.3 - though I don't see release notes on their site for anything later than 3.2 so maybe they are not "core" updates. Of course PHPDoc is not handled by "core" but by the PHP Bundle. You could use the Aptana plugin through Eclipse with PDT and get this functionality, or I believe you can get Aptana Studio 2 with PDT which would allow this as well.

Comment: I installed PDT as plugin in Aptana 3, looked in configuration to make sure PHPdoc was enabled in `PHP -> Editor -> Typing`. I right clicked on my project -> Configure and `add php support` but whenever I type `/**` + `enter` in front of a simple php function with parameters or a class, nothing is filled automatically. I'll try to install many plugins in eclipse to make it feel like aptana if I have some time. Here's a related post by the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031680/aptana-wont-generate-phpdoc-blocks-for-functions-within-classes

It is marked as solved but did not work here

Answer (score 0):

I use NetBeans with php and it automatically enters your variables, return, and throws. Just type /** and hit enter. The code in the method has to be completed in order for it to fully generate the returns and throws.